# Passing information through delegates not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, maps

How's its setup is that when you click a location which is inside a tableview, its sends the coordinates to the MapController though delegates. I made a protocol and created a delegate variable in the receiver controller. I have also implemented the methods in the protocol to the receiver controller.

When you click the tableview cell, it prints "Item Pressed" + location, because of the test print statements but data is not getting carried over and the pin is not getting placed on the map.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import CoreLocationUI
import FloatingPanel


protocol SearchViewControllerDelegate : AnyObject {
    func searchViewController(_ vc: SearchViewController, didSelectLocationWith coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?)
}

class SearchViewController : UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    
     var delegateSelect: SearchViewControllerDelegate?
    
    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return tableView
    }()
    private let label: UILabel={
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Where To"
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .semibold)
        return label
    }()
    
   private let field : UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "Enter Destination"
        field.backgroundColor = .tertiarySystemBackground
       field.layer.cornerRadius = 9
        field.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 50))
        field.leftViewMode = .always
        return field
    }()
    
    var locations = [Location]()
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = locations[indexPath.row].title
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        cell.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return locations.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        // Notify map controller to show pin
        let coordinate = locations[indexPath.row].coordinates
        print(coordinate ?? 666)

        delegateSelect?.searchViewController(self, didSelectLocationWith: coordinate)
    
        print("Item pressed")
    }
 
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        field.resignFirstResponder()
        if let text = field.text, !text.isEmpty {
            LocationManager.shared.findLocations(with:text){[weak self] locations in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.locations = locations
                    self?.tableView.reloadData()
                }
        }
    }
        return true
    }
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.addSubview(field)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
      
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        field.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width:view.frame.size.width, height:label.frame.size.height)
        field.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20+label.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.size.width-20, height:50)
        let tableY: CGFloat = field.frame.origin.y+field.frame.size.height+5
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: tableY, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height-tableY)
    }
    
}
```

Receiving View Controller

```
   import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import CoreLocationUI
import FloatingPanel



class MapController : UIViewController, SearchViewControllerDelegate {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private let map: MKMapView = {
        let map = MKMapView()
        
        return map
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Map"
        checkLocationAuthorization()
        checkUserLoggedIn()
    }

    func checkUserLoggedIn (){
        
        if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
            print("Not logged in")
             //print not logged in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let nav = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginScreenController") as! LoginScreenController
                self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            }
            print(" User is not logged in learn to spell")
        }
        else{
            print (" User ID is \(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)")
            setHomeScreenView()
            print("test")
        }
    }
  
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        map.frame=view.bounds
        
    }

    func signUserOut(){
        
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            print("User signed out")
        } catch {
            print("Debug: Error signing out")
            
        }
    }

    func setHomeScreenView(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(map)
        let searchVC = SearchViewController()
        searchVC.delegateSelect = self
        let panel = FloatingPanelController()
        panel.set(contentViewController: SearchViewController())
        panel.addPanel(toParent: self)
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.userTrackingMode = .follow
  
    }
    
    func checkLocationAuthorization() { 
        
            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
            case .authorizedWhenInUse:
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                break
            case .denied:
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                break
            case .notDetermined:
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            case .restricted:
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                break
            case .authorizedAlways:
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            }
        }
    
    func searchViewController(_ vc: SearchViewController, didSelectLocationWith coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?) {
        guard let coordinates = coordinates else {
            print("tesssst")
            return
        }
        map.removeAnnotations(map.annotations)
        print("owotest")
        let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
        pin.coordinate = coordinates
        map.addAnnotation(pin)
        map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.7, longitudeDelta: 0.7)), animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you set the search map view controller as the delegate of the search view controller?

Comment: I edited that in in the main post

Comment: You are creating an instance of `SearchViewController` as a local variable so it will be discarded as soon as `viewDidLoad` returns.  You need to set the delegate on the actual instance that will be on screen. If you use segues this will be in `prepare(for:sender:)`

Comment: I don't use a segue tho. The user selects one table cell from a floating panel and then it updates on the map controller. Any idea where I could put this?

Comment: You need to get a reference to the map controller that is on screen. How do you display it? Are you using a container view controller to show the search view controller and the map controller at the same time?

Comment: yep. im using a floating panel to show the searchview on top of the map view

Comment: You need to get the map view controller set as the delegate property of the search view controller.  At some point in your code you must have a reference to both view controllers. That is where you set the delegate. Can you edit your question to show how you set up both view controllers?

Comment: Mhm, I added the whole code for both controllers